# Access parent page variable from child page?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, parent-child, return-value

I want to pass a value from a child page to my parent page:

Parent page script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var popup;
    function SelectName() {
        popup = window.open("SelDestination.aspx", "Select", "width=500,height=300");
        popup.focus();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

On child page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="انتخاب"  OnClientClick="SetName();" />
```

And child page script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function SetName() {
         if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
             var ddlName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtDes");
             //var e = document.getElementById("<%=ddlOffice.ClientID %>");
             ddlName.value = "Hi";
         }
         window.close();
     }
```

But it doesn't work correctly (I have a runtime error: ddlname is null or undefined)!

Any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar It's just a var name.

Comment: @Masoodtav on the child page script, remove opener, just keep: `window.document.getElementById("txtDes");`

Comment: @Superdrac It don't work correctly! Of course "txtDes" is on my parent page!

Comment: Please confirm if the error message is exactly as you see it. You have this var ddlName, but in the error it suggests a different variable name ddlname. Is this a spelling mistake on your side, or is it in the code?

Comment: @HappyHamburger "ddlName" is just name for variable.
I copy error here:
Unhandled exception at line 11, column 18 in http://localhost:14983/SelDestintion.aspx

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0):

Make a javascript file and do this in head:

```
<script src="path/to/ye/js"></script>
```

And remember to do it in both sites.
Then add this variable to to javascript file.